# Text Flow to HTML

Tags: java, html

I receive a String which is passed on through a flex application and has text flow format as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<TextFlow fontFamily='Arial' fontSize='16' paddingBottom='2' paddingLeft='2'
          paddingRight='2' paddingTop='2' whiteSpaceCollapse='preserve'
          version='2.0.0' xmlns='http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008'>
  <p>
    <span>Word1</span>
    <span fontWeight='bold'>Word2</span>
    <span fontSize='22' fontWeight='bold'>Word 3</span>
    <span baselineShift='superscript' fontSize='22'
          fontWeight='normal'>Word4superscript</span>
  </p>
</TextFlow>
```

How can i convert this to HTML that i can use this in my java application keeping all the font sizes and color span?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TextConverter class to transform TextFlow into an html string.

```
import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;
import flashx.textLayout.conversion.ConversionType;

var output:Object = TextConverter.export(textFlow,TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT, ConversionType.STRING_TYPE)
```

Where textFlow is the it the variable containing your TextFlow object.

More information detailing importing and exporting with TextFlow can be found here:

http://flex4fun.com/2010/11/30/flex4-export-textflow-data/